# how to read exact cell content of excel file in apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

when I read a content of cell for e.g. if it is in date format it casts into some another value like 12/31/2099 -> 46052 and $50.00 -> 50 and 50.00% -> 0.5.

But what I want is to get the exact string value for every cell.

My Code is like this:

```
cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
String str = cell.getStringCellValue();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for explicit formatting, Apache POI provides for [`DataFormatter`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html) class as utility to leverage the format of the content *as it appears* on the excel. You can choose custom formats too, a simple example would be (cell is reference to your `XSSFCell` object):

```
System.out.println(new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(cell));
```

Excel sheet looks like:

[image]

Using `DataFormatter` (sop statement above) prints:

```
50%
$ 1,200
12/21/14
```

Where your normal formatting would print:

```
0.5
1200.0
21-Dec-2014
```

Comment: Tx, it was exactly what I needed. Did not know the cell uses internally different Format types

Answer (score 0):

I would not try and alter the data type while I am reading.

Instead of that, I would try to

- get the cell type first of all
- then use the appropiate getter method for each data type

For example:

```
// Let's say you have prepared a DecimalFormat yourNumberFormatter and a
// DateFormat yourDateFormatter with the format that is appropiate to your
// presentation 
Cell cell = ...;
String value = null;
switch (cell.getCellType()) {
   case Cell.TYPE_NUMERIC:
     // Date format
     if ( DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell) ) {
        value = yourDateFormatter.format(cell.getDateCellValue());
     }
     else {
        value = yourNumberFormatter.format(cell.getNumericCellValue());
     }
     break;
   case Cell.TYPE_STRING:
     value = cell.getStringCellValue();
     break;
  // Etc.
}
```

Comment: I wanted to handle all cell types like currency, ssn, etc. I think DateUtil is only for handling DateType cells

Comment: Yes, you are right.  The problem is that things like "currency" are a combination between numeric format and a specific style for the excel cell; you will need to finetune the numeric case entry in order to separe each case you have and produce an adecuate presentation of the number your read